# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c

Tags: ios, objective-c

my application keeps crashing because of the below error. I tried debugging it but am not able to understand why is it caused and how to debug and remove this..

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x335cef46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x29307c2b -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
2  UIKit                          0x29307bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
3  UIKit                          0x292f2863 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 582
4  UIKit                          0x2930763d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588
5  UIKit                          0x29307317 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
6  UIKit                          0x29300be1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 544
7  UIKit                          0x292d73dd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
8  UIKit                          0x2954ac29 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13888
9  UIKit                          0x292d5e39 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1296
10 CoreFoundation                 0x25dde377 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
11 CoreFoundation                 0x25ddd787 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
12 CoreFoundation                 0x25ddbded __CFRunLoopRun + 772
13 CoreFoundation                 0x25d2a211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
14 CoreFoundation                 0x25d2a023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15 GraphicsServices               0x2d1230a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
16 UIKit                          0x293361d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
17 Application                    0x000ffefb main (main.m:17)
```

Comment: That's a NULL pointer dereference. Check for uninitialized variables, or variables initialized to NULL/nil and never set to a valid pointer. Hard to say much else without seeing the code where it's crashing.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to capture all exceptions - http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions this might help track down where the error is

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Flexicoder.
@Flexicoder the challenge is that this issue is not happening very frequently. So is there some way i can push something similar to exception breakpoint in the build and push it to production .. so that the next time it happens i come to know. Because otherwise i will have to try and reproduce that issue which doesnt look that easy.

Comment: You could embed Flurry to get Crash Analytics http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics - it might help

Comment: @Siddhant Jain did you get success in finding the root cause of this issue?